# No funciona Grid en css

Tags: html, css

les pido a ustedes su ayuda para solucionar el siguiente problema. Estoy haciendo un ejercico de CSS grid de un tutorial y estoy usando la herramienta de layoutit y asi es como tiene que quedar el grid como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo asi me esta saliendo como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que seguí las instrucciones al pie de la letra cuando en el video empezo a usar empezó a usar el layoutit Pero como pueden ver no esta funcionando. ya intente todo. Por favor les pido su ayuda a solucionar este problema para que se vea como en la primera imagen. muchas gracias

Aqui esta el link del video del tutorial de esta maquetacion en grid.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htzLVAcZ0B4&t=6s

En el minuto 33:35 del video es cuando empieza a usar el layoutit

aui esta el codigo en html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title> PORTAFOLIO PERSONAL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="menu">
        <div class="tile about-tile">
            <a href="#about">
                <div class="front"> </div>
                <div class="back"> ABAOUT</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile projects-tile">
            <a href="#projects">
                <div class="front"> </div>
                <div class="back"> PROYECTS</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile posts-tile">
            <a href="#posts">
                <div class="front"> </div>
                <div class="back"> POSTS</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile contact-tile">
            <a href="#contact">
                <div class="front"> </div>
                <div class="back"> CONTACT</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
        <div class="tile tile-1">
            <div>
                <h2>STACK</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <img src="img/react.png" alt="React" width="100">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-2">
            <div>
                <h2>ABAOUT</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum Iste quisquam numquam libero ad. Minima blanditiis praesentium sed voluptate illo, reprehenderit, incidunt temporibus commodi ut a iusto ab harum, recusandae velit.</p>
                <img src="img/profile.png" alt="Profile" width="100">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-3">
            <div>
                <h2>STACK</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <img src="img/microsoft.png" alt="Microsoft" width="100">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-4">
            <div>
                <h2>SERVICES</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <img src="img/cloud.png" alt="cloud services" width="100">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile-5">
            <div>
                <h2>AWARDS</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <img src="img/trophy.png" alt="trophy" width="100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="projects">
        <div class="tile main-photo">
            <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque qui,
                 omnis, consequatur exercitationem consequuntur magnam neque totam 
                 quidem sapiente corporis enim in doloribus cumque, reprehenderit
                  praesentium tenetur maiores distinctio illum?
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-2">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-3">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-4">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-5">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-6">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-7">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-8">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-9">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-10">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-11">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-12">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-13">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-14">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-15">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-16">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile.photo-17">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui esta el codigo en css.

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu{
    background-color: rgb(195, 35, 88);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 200px);
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "about about projects projects"
    "about about posts contact";
}

#menu .tile{
    height: 100%;
  
    overflow: hidden;
    
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu .tile a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu .tile .front{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#menu .tile .back{
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}

#menu .tile:hover .front{
    margin-top: -100%;
}

#menu .projects-tile:hover .front{
    margin-top: -50%;
}

#menu .about-tile .front{
    background-image: url(img/profile.png);
}

#menu .projects-tile .front{
    background-image: url(img/work-01.png);
}

#menu .posts-tile .front{
    background-image: url(img/work-02.png);
}

#menu .contact-tile .front{
    background-image: url(img/work-03.png);
}

.about-tile{
    grid-area: about;
}

.projects-tile{
    grid-area: projects;
}

/************************************************
                ABAOUT
*************************************************/

#about{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#about .tile{
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    background-color: #eee;

    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}

#about .tile-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

#about .tile-2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

#about .tile-2 img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#projects {  
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-2 photo-2 photo-2 photo-3 photo-3 photo-4 photo-4"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-2 photo-2 photo-2 photo-3 photo-3 photo-4 photo-4"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-2 photo-2 photo-2 photo-5 photo-17 photo-4 photo-4"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-7 photo-7 photo-6 photo-6 photo-6 photo-9 photo-9"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-7 photo-7 photo-6 photo-6 photo-6 photo-9 photo-9"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-7 photo-7 photo-8 photo-8 photo-8 photo-8 photo-8"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-10 photo-10 photo-8 photo-8 photo-8 photo-8 photo-8"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-10 photo-10 photo-11 photo-11 photo-11 photo-12 photo-12"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-13 photo-14 photo-11 photo-11 photo-11 photo-12 photo-12"
      "main-photo main-photo main-photo photo-15 photo-16 photo-11 photo-11 photo-11 photo-12 photo-12";
  }
  
  #projects .tile{
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .main-photo { grid-area: main-photo; }
  
  .photo-2 { grid-area: photo-2; }
  
  .photo-3 { grid-area: photo-3; }
  
  .photo-4 { grid-area: photo-4; }
  
  .photo-5 {
    grid-area: photo-5;
  }
  
  .photo-17 { grid-area: photo-17; }
  
  .photo-7 { grid-area: photo-7; }
  
  .photo-6 { grid-area: photo-6; }
  
  .photo-9 { grid-area: photo-9; }
  
  .photo-10 { grid-area: photo-10; }
  
  .photo-8 { grid-area: photo-8; }
  
  .photo-13 { grid-area: photo-13; }
  
  .photo-14 { grid-area: photo-14; }
  
  .photo-15 { grid-area: photo-15; }
  
  .photo-16 { grid-area: photo-16; }
  
  .photo-11 { grid-area: photo-11; }
  
  .photo-12 { grid-area: photo-12; }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Vas al video, presionas "mostrar más" abajo de él y dice "Descarga los archivos del tutorial" y ahí está tu código. No veo que podamos aportar algo más claro nosotros. https://github.com/marcosrivasr/sitio-web-grid